# How to find a line $x = b$ so that the sum of distances of a set of points from the line is minimal

Tags: calculus

Given a set of N points $\{(x_1, y_1),...,(x_n, y_n)\}$, I need to find a line parallel to the y-axis $x = b$ so that $f(b) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i - b|$ is the minimum, but I am not sure how to derive this function or if I even can derive it.

A script I wrote for small groups (3 to 20 points) with x values of -100 to 100 (integers only) found that if N is odd then the minimal $b$ is the median of N (could be around it as I use only integers) and if N is even then the minimal $b$ is every integer between the lower median and the upper median, but I don't know how to prove this for every N and all points in the xy-plane.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll assume the $x_i$ are unique. You want to minimize the sum of absolute values of linear terms. In this case, the function $\sum_{i=1}^n |b-x_i| $ first decreases till the ‘middle’ and then increases. To see this, start with $b$ less than the smallest $x_i$. All the mod signs open with a negative sign giving a line of a highly negative slope. Now move $b$ to the right. Surpassing each point thereafter increases the coefficient of $b$ and so you get lines of less and less negative slopes, until you reach a point when

*Case 1: $n$ is even*

$\frac n2$ terms open with positive and negative signs each, giving a line of zero slope. Increasing $b$ more will give positive sloped lines. Hence, choose any $b$ on the zero slope line.

*Case 2: $n$ is odd*

The slope of the lines goes from $-1$ to $1$, so there’s exactly one minimal point (when $b$ is at the median).

There’s no point using calculus here, as we’re dealing with a bunch of mods which have sharp non-differentiate extremums.